# Macbook pro display problem: orange "smudge" appears near edge

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware

Recently there have been weird display problems on my Macbook Pro (late-2016 model with touchbar, MacOS Sierra, Intel HD graphics 530 1536 MB).

**Problem**

I have included two photos of my screen, the first one in original color and the second one I edited the photo to make color differences more obvious. Notice that the left edge of the screen is orange-ish. On the other hand, screenshots taken by say command+shift+4 are perfectly normal (which is why I had to take photos...sorry for the bad photo quality).

This orange-ish "smudge" only appears when I put my laptop in the upright position for more than an hour (like in my backpack or against the wall), and the smudge only appears near whichever edge at the bottom. If I keep the laptop on a flat surface (like on a table), the smudge slowly goes away. It almost feels like something is flowing through the screen to accumulate at a low point.

**Question**

Is this a display (hardware) problem as I thought? What is the underlying cause? Is it fixable/repairable? I have been bugged by this problem for some time and google was not helpful...any input is appreciated! Thank you so much!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem. Have you tried running [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) and/or a GPU heavy workload like [Unigine Heaven](https://benchmark.unigine.com/heaven) or [Gputest](http://www.geeks3d.com/gputest/)?

Comment: This looks like a display issue.  Try taking a screen shot, if the "smudge" is not there, it's likely your display.

Comment: @Allan Agreed. Running GPU tests should narrow it down though to a screen issue (they already indicated that the screenshots didn't contain the splotches.)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, and I've now had it *twice* within the first year. Not good. They say it's a defective panel and just replace the screen, but I'm not convinced they're finding the actual cause. I mean, it could be two defective panels in a row, but how likely is that? Did you ever find an actual *cause*?

Comment: if you press the orange areas you can actually see it move around the screen! Suspecting its something to do with the pigment they use for nightshift mode...but im no engineer.

Comment: I know this might be late, but my 2017 Macbook pro has the same problem. It is very subtle orangish color mostly at the corners, but allover the screen. When I put my Macbook in my back pack and go to school, the edge of the screen that was at the bottom of the bag and under pressure, shows extreme discoloration. What ever it is, it is related to the screen itself and pressure related. As I leave it off, lying closed and normal on my desk, after a few hours, discoloration at the edge disappears. But the rest of it (which was subtle allover) remains.

Comment: @NavidRajil Hi, man. I live almost the same problem with yours'. My Macbook is also 2017 and 15 inch.   How did you solve the problem? I'm just curious. 
Interesting point is that, when I put my Macbook on straight surface, the yellow stain on the bottom-left starts to disappear. Then, when I put the my Macbook to my bag and get it out after few hours to work, I see the stain is there on bottom-left and then it disappears again after keeping it on the straight surface. I'm really confused.

Comment: @Ali Zeynalov: I took it to Apple Store for repair. They replaced the screen and now it is fine. I only had 5 days of warranty left! So if you still have warranty or even better, AppleCare, take it to them and they will fix the problem at no cost. Other wise, I think you have to pay for the repairs.

Comment: I have the same problem. According to my experience It happended due to daily travel and placing the macbook 2017 15" vertically upside down in the bag. when I change the side the yellow spot shift to that side. I also noticed placing the bag vertically on the chair for an hour the spot is still there. If i place the bag on the desk or the macbook spot disappears after few hours.

The solution is to turn off the macbook and then carry it in the bag otherwise this issue starts after few months. My warranty is expired.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue on my 2017 15'' MBP.  So are a thousand other people.   https://gregsamborski.com/macbook-pro-led-screen-discoloration-spots-15-2017-touch-bar/

Comment: I had this issue: the bottom of the screen had orange hue. Solution that worked for me was switching off "True tone" in Display settings and waiting a bit for the orange hue to disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a display issue.

If you think it's defective, take it in to an Apple Store and you may be able to convince them to replace it for free and/or at a discount.

If it's accidental damage you don't have many options other than paying for a repair or living with it.