# Orange smudge/splotch near edge of screen on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a Macbook Pro w/ Touch Bar, and on the corner of my screen there is a dark orange discoloration. It appears every now and then in different locations of the screen and then dissipates with time.

I want to know if this is normal or something that I need to fix.

[image]

Comment: Similar https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309577/macbook-pro-display-problem-orange-smudge-appears-near-edge?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

That is not normal in that it wouldn’t be made that way, but it’s normal since it’s understandable how it could happen. That is a cosmetic issue with the LCD panel. Without a physical inspection or examining the panel, my best guess is the layers are compressed physically. No need to repair it until you can’t or won’t abide by the color shift or the area just stops working.

Get a quote for how much it would cost to fix it, then consider:

- putting that cash in a jar and deciding if you’d rather save it for your next computer or an iPad or a brand new external display.

That way the money is there to unlock something you want in the future as a post to a nagging doubt that your current machine has a flaw in it. If Apple wants to cover it under warranty, r dilemma is solved so definitely get a quote for repair.

As to the coming and going, If you carry your Mac in the book bag or it could be getting otherwise squeezed, that would explain why the color moves around in the dissipates as the glass and plastic layers reset themselves.  Like a thin film of oil or soap on water, you are seeing a rainbow of diffraction and refraction as the light and LCD interact with each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal. There are other people having similar issues.

https://gregsamborski.com/macbook-pro-led-screen-discoloration-spots-15-2017-touch-bar/

Many suggest that it is related to:

1. the overheating of the main body
2. the pressure on the LCD screen when putting the MacBook Pro in a bagpack

Comment: Heat seems a very unlikely cause - what reason would the heat pattern be so strong in areas that shift. You can also measure temperature very accurately with infrared thermometers so that should be easy to prove or disprove.

Comment: Because when you close the lid, the areas of the display that are experiencing the discoloration are that along the periphery that sit nearly flush against the hot aluminum chassis.   Moreover, as one whose book is also experiencing it, the only way I've found to mitigate it, is to shut down completely and allow to cool before closing and storing (often going as far as to insert a thin piece of foam paper as well as a buffer).